# How to use celery rdb while working with python, flask, docker and docker compose?

Tags: python, docker, debugging, docker-compose, celery

I use python, flask, celery, docker and docker compose in my project and wanted to use [celery rdb](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/reference/celery.contrib.rdb.html) to debug my tasks. I could not connect to celery container using telnet from my local machine to docker container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find an easy way to do it. Finally I ended up with followings:

1. install telnet into celery container (add on following Dockerfile )

```bash
# install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y telnet
```

2. trigger celery task. you will see logs output like this:
   Remote Debugger:6900: Ready to connect: telnet 127.0.0.1 6900
3. go into the celery container in another terminal

```bash
docker compose exec my_celery bash
```

4. run telnet command

```bash
root@fc4dcaa378xy:/usr/src/app# telnet 0.0.0.0 6900
    Trying 0.0.0.0...
    Connected to 0.0.0.0.
    Escape character is '^]'.
    > /usr/src/app/api/tasks.py(55)my_task()
    -> scraper_res = myfunc(url, *args, **kwargs)
    (Pdb) pp locals()
```